# Missing "this" keyword in javascript setter, getter methods

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, this

I accidentally missing this keyword inside setter, getter methods. It leads to some weird bugs: (tested with Chrome, Firefox)

**Case 1**:

```
let user = {
    name: "John",

    set fullName(value) {
        name = value;
    },

    get fullName() {
        return name;
    }
};

user.fullName // ""
user.fullName = "Batman"
user.fullName // "Batman"
user.name // "John"
```

Why is property **name** still "John" ? Where did "Batman" come from?

**Case 2**: change variable name of the above code, something happens:

```
let user = {
    anythingButName: "John",

    set fullName(value) {
        anythingButName = value;
    },

    get fullName() {
        return anythingButName;
    }

    user.fullName // anythingButName is not defined at Object.get fullName [as fullName]...
};
```

Can't use any name but the word **name** for the variable in above code. I don't know why?

Comment: console.log(window.name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both cases are equal. What happens:

```
let user = {
  name: "John",

set fullName(value) {
    name = value;//sets window.name to *value*
},

get fullName() {
    return name;//returns window.name
}
};

console.log(
user.fullName,// window.name is "" by default
window.name,
user.fullName = "Batman", //=> window.name
window.name,
user.fullName, // "Batman" ==window.name
user.name // "John" //what you really wanted
);
```

It *works* ( not really ) just with *name* as *window.name* is a default property and therefore set to "" at the beginning.
You can check in your second case:

```
console.log(
  user.fullName, // undefined yet
  user.fullName="test",
  user.fullName // test
);
```